# I can't change the user's password

Tags: laravel

If I want to change the password, the codes are working properly, do not 
show any mistakes, but it looks incorrect if you want to log in with a new 
password. I saw in the database, there was no password change.

```
public function postPasswordReset(Request $request)
{
    $validator = validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email'     =>  'required|exists:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|alpha_num|between:6,32',
            're-password' => 'required|same:password'
        ]);

    if($validator->passes()){

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        $user->update(['password' bcrypt($request->password)]);

        return redirect()->route('auth.login');
    }
     return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())-
     >withInput();
}
```

Comment: typo : missing =>        $user->update(['password' =>bcrypt($request->password)]);

Comment: thanks JYoThi, it's work. thanks for your supporting.

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update method you are using an array to update in a wrong format. Try this one

```
$user->update(['password' => bcrypt($request->password)]);
```